# how to call c# dll from vbscript

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com, vbscript, visual-studio-2005

Hi I am creating a c# dll with below code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace imageexport
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class ExportImage
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public void exportPNG(String pDirectory,String svgFileName,String outputFileName) {
            String arguments= pDirectory+"res\\include\\highcharts-convert.js -infile "+pDirectory+"res\\graphs\\"+svgFileName+" -outfile "+pDirectory+"res\\graphs\\"+outputFileName +" -scale 2.5 -width 1088";
            /*using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\debug.txt", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("pDirectory=" +pDirectory);
                writer.WriteLine("arguments="+arguments);
            }*/
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = pDirectory+"res\\bin\\phantomjs.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

For creating dll I do configuration as below in VS2005

```
Application
     Assembly Name -> imageexport
      Default Namespace - > imageexport
     outputtype => Classlibrary
     startup object ->(Not Set)
   Assembly Information :
         a) Assembly Version ->1 0 0 0
         b)File Version ->1 0 0 0
         c) Make Assembly Com visible ->checked
 Build 
  Configuration -> Active (Debug)
  Platform ->Active (Any CPU)
  General :
    a)conditional Compilation Symbols -> blank
     b) Define Debug Constant ->checked
    c) Define Trace Constant -> checked
    d) platform Target -> Any CPU
    e) allow unsafe code -> not checked
    f) optimize code -> not checked
    g) warning lavel -> 4
    h) Supperess warning -> blank 
    i) Treat Warnign errors -> None
```

Now after this I register the imageexport.dll with regasm of .net 2.0

Now when I look registry then under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT I found imageexport.ExportImage.

Now in vbscript below code is use to create object and call the function

```
Dim obj                        
Set obj = CreateObject("imageexport.ExportImage")
obj.exportPNG rvPAWZDirectoryPath&"\","SVGData_"&Session("export_time")&".svg","Export_" & export_time & ".png"
```

But this give exception named 'UnknownException' at the line createObject in VBSCript. Please tell me where is the problem

Comment: What happens if you run exportPNG from a C# client? Just wonder if that is throwing.

Comment: No, When I use this dll in c# console application then it works fine.

Comment: Hi, now when I uncomment the file writing code, and run this after system restart then debug.txt is creating fine. Now the only issue is phantomjs.exe is not getting execute, while this gets execute when I call this from console application.

Answer (score 8):

I think you should register your Dll as:

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>regasm yourDllPath /codebase
```

Now you can create object of your Dll.